# createObjectURL roundtrip through sqlite fails to show image

Tags: javascript, image, web-sql

I'm trying to display an image retrieved from websql using the createObjectURL. I put together the code below to test whether I can save and retrieve data from the database.
Prior to saving the image in the DB, I can create the objectURL and it displays on the screen correctly - after fetching the data from the DB however, nothing is displayed - or rather a default 'icon' is displayed. 
I've compared the data being written and retrieved from the DB and everything appears to be identical. I've scratched my head over this and searched the net and am no closer to an answer.
I'd be grateful for any suggestions/help with what I am doing wrong.
The codec was from [here](http://phpjs.org/functions/base64_encode/) and [here](http://phpjs.org/functions/base64_decode/).

I'm running chrome (28.0.1500.71) from the command line using the following options:

google-chrome --disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-files --unlimited-storage

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<!-- pick any encode/decode pair - this pair seemed to work fine -->
<script src="js/base64_encode.js"></script>
<script src="js/base64_decode.js"></script>

<script>
function run(){
    var gendate = new Date().getTime()
    var encode = base64_encode; // replace this with whatever encode/decode pair
    var decode = base64_decode; // replace this with whatever encode/decode pair
    var codec = "base64_encode_decode";
    var input, b64input;
    var output, b64output;
    var filename = "small.png"  //add any file in your system
    var key = gendate+filename;

    console.log("Codec: "+ codec);
    var db = window.openDatabase("tmpdb", "1.0", "Sql Test DB", 5 * 1024 * 1024, function(){
        console.log("success")
    }, function(e){
        console.log(e);
    });

    function put(){
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', filename , false);
        req.overrideMimeType('text\/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
        req.onerror = function(){
            console.log("ERROR: "+req.StatusText);
        }
        req.onload = function () {
            console.log("Input file size: " +req.response.length);
            var start = new Date().getTime()
            input = showImage(req.response);
            var data = encode(req.response);
            b64input = data;
            console.log("encode duration: "+ (new Date().getTime()-start));
            console.log("Encoded size: " + data.length);
            function _run () {
                console.log("Wrote " + key);
                db.transaction( function (tx) {
                    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmptable  (key, body NONE)');
                    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO tmptable (key, body) VALUES (?, ?)',[key, data]);
                    get();
                });
            }
            _run();
        }
        req.send(null);
    }

    function get(){
        db.transaction( function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('Select body from tmptable where key=?', [key],
                function(tx, result){
                    var start = new Date().getTime()
                    b64output = result.rows.item(0).body;
                    var data = decode(result.rows.item(0).body)
                    output = data;
                    console.log("decode duration: "+ (new Date().getTime()-start));
                    console.log("Output data size: "+ data.length);
                    output = showImage(data);
                    if (b64input === b64output) {
                        console.log("b64 matched")
                    } else {
                        console.log("b64 not matched");
                    }
                    compareArray(input, output)
                }, function(err){
                    console.log("ERROR: ", err)
                });
        });
    }

    function compareArray(input, output){
        var match = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < input; i++) {
            if (input[i] !== output[i]){
                console.log("Arrays not matched at: " +i);
                match = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (match) { console.log("Arrays match")};
    }
    function showImage( data ) {
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(data.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            byteArray[i] = data.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff;
        }
        var blob = new Blob([byteArray.buffer], {type:"image/png"});
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.onload = function() {
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(blob);
        };
        img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        document.body.appendChild(img);
        return byteArray;
    }
    put();
}
</script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body onload="run()">
</body>
</html>
```

Console output is as below:

```
Codec: base64_encode_decode
Input file size: 670 
encode duration: 4 
Encoded size: 896 
Wrote 1374988636651small.png 
decode duration: 1 
Output data size: 670 
b64 matched 
Arrays match
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the question is resolved, but not in the way that I expected it. For one thing, I bypassed the external encode/decode functions using the blob type in the ajax request (arraybuffer also worked, but had an additional step to make the blob from it), and had to use a FileReader/readAsDataURL to convert it to base64 before storing in the DB.

One of the key benefits of doing it this way seems to be that the resulting base64 encoding is compatible with the standard atob function. I could never get the btoa function to covert a binary to base64 - if that worked as expected, then a few more steps could be cut from the process.

When converting it back to blob, I used atob to make the base64 binary, and then converted that into blob via an ArrayBuffer (the code for that was borrowed from the net - I don't remember exactly where and I apologise for that, but this was the only conversion I found that worked correctly - if the author recognises the code - please post a comment with the URL for all of our future benefit), which then displayed correctly using the createObjectURL.

Although I did make the roundtrip work correctly in the end after borrowing suggestions and examples from the net, it seems a rather roundabout way of getting to the solution. If anyone has a better/simpler solution - feel free to add a comment.

Seems to me that the base64 encoding and decoding is the thing that required a number of additional steps - and also the fact that I couldn't store/retrieve a blob/binary directly into sqlite - or has someone discovered a way to do it? If so please add a comment :)

The code I ended up using is below (minus console logs), for my and anyone else's future reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script>
function run(){
    var gendate = new Date().getTime()
    var filename = "small.png"  //add any file in your system
    var key = gendate+filename;
    var db = window.openDatabase("sqldb", "1.0", "Sql Test DB", 5 * 1024 * 1024, function(){
        console.log("success")
    }, function(e){
        console.log(e);
    });

    function put(){
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', filename , false);
        req.overrideMimeType('text\/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
        req.responseType = "blob";
        req.onerror = function(){
            console.log("ERROR: "+req.StatusText);
        }
        req.onload = function () {
            showImage(req.response);
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function(e) {
                data = reader.result.replace(/^data:.+;base64,/, '');
                db.transaction( function (tx) {
                    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmptable  (key, body NONE)');
                    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO tmptable (key, body) VALUES (?, ?)',[key, data]);
                    get();
                });
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(req.response);
        }
        req.send(null);
    }

    function get(){
        db.transaction( function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('Select body from tmptable where key=?', [key],
                function(tx, result){
                    var data = atob(result.rows.item(0).body)
                    var barray = new Uint8Array(data.length);
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        barray[i] = data.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff;
                    }
                    blob = new Blob([barray], {type:"image/png"});
                    showImage(blob);
                }, function(err){
                    console.log("ERROR: ", err)
                });
        });
    }
    function showImage( blob) {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.onload = function() {
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(blob);
        };
        img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
    put();
}
</script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body onload="run()">
</body>
</html>
```